pandas : text to xlsx
I'm trying to convert a txt file with delimiters into an Excel file
Target:

Current:

(they're all bunched together on column A)
The first row has commas, and row 2 onwards |
import pandas as pd

input_file_path = 'path.txt'
output_file_path = 'path.xlsm'
                            
df = pd.read_csv(input_file_path, sep='|', header=None)

df.drop([0], inplace=True)

df.to_excel(output_file_path, index=False, header=False)

print("File saved successfully.")

Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong?
Thank you

Please show the CSV in raw text format
